# Kernel Error in Anaconda Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, list, anaconda, sublime-anaconda

I have started learning python and in the initial stage i am not be able to execute any code on python. While searching over the google, i found that it occurs due to **kernel error** and same is reflecting on the top and trust box is disabled. I have re-installed the software 2/3 times and Anti Virus program was also disabled until software gets installed properly on system. But it didn't work. I am attaching the screen shot for your reference.

I am totally new in the programming end and hence if you could explain me what exactly needs to be install step by step it would be helpful to make things done easily. There are many posts wherein answers are mentioned, but i didn't understand how those code to be executed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please try out by creating a new conda environment.
Create conda environment using the command :

```
conda create -n <env_name> -c intel python=3.6
```

Activate the environmemt using the command :

```
source activate <env_name>
```

Please install the required packages in this environment.
Kindly install the ipykernal using the command:

```
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name <env_name> --user
```

Select the installed ipykernal from your jupyter notebook.
Hope this helps.

Please refer the following link, `https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2301`